# Error When Running Developement Nuxtjs

Tags: nuxt.js

I have installed nuxtjs, but when i try npm run dev i get this error :

```
aep@ ~/projects/nuxt-learn $ npm run dev 

> nuxt-learn@1.0.0 dev /home/aep/projects/nuxt-learn
> nuxt

/home/aep/projects/nuxt-learn/node_modules/nuxt/lib/core/middleware/nuxt.js:72
      const policies = this.options.render.csp.policies ? {...this.options.render.csp.policies} : null
                                                           ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aep/projects/nuxt-learn/node_modules/nuxt/lib/core/renderer.js:19:24)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nuxt-learn@1.0.0 dev: `nuxt`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nuxt-learn@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/aep/.npm/_logs/2018-03-11T15_02_34_778Z-debug.log
```

my current npm v.5.0.3, node version is 8.1.4 and nuxt version is 1.0.0. I developement project on Linux Mint Rossa 17.3
Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been solved by use latest version of node:

**SOLUTION**: I intsall 8.10.0 of node